# Integrate polynomials using symbolic computation

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, matrix, performance-tuning, symbolic

I have a problem with integrating the next construction. The last operation (integration itself) lasts for too long. Is it possible to accelerate it using symbolic tools?

```
 Nform = {((1 - k) (1 - p))/4, ((1 + k) (1 - p))/
       4, ((1 + k) (1 + p))/4, ((1 - k) (1 + p))/4};
    x = Nform.{x1, x2, x3, x4};
    y = Nform.{y1, y2, y3, y4};
    Delem = (EEE (1 - nu))/((1 + nu) (1 - 2 nu)) {
        {1, nu/(1 - nu), 0},
        {nu/(1 - nu), 1, 0},
        {0, 0, (1 - 2 nu)/(2 (1 - nu))}
        };
    IM = D[x, k] D[y, p] - D[x, p] D[y, k];
    B = {{D[Nform[[1]], k], 0, D[Nform[[2]],k], 0, 
        D[Nform[[3]], k], 0, D[Nform[[4]], k], 0},
       {0, D[Nform[[1]], p], 0, D[Nform[[2]], p], 0, 
        D[Nform[[3]], p], 0, D[Nform[[4]],p]},
       {D[Nform[[1]],p], D[Nform[[1]], k], 
        D[Nform[[2]], p], D[Nform[[2]], k], 
        D[Nform[[3]], p], D[Nform[[3]], k], 
        D[Nform[[4]], p], D[Nform[[4]], k]}} ;
    MP = IM * Transpose[B].Delem.B ;
    Kel = Integrate[MP, {k, 0, 1}, {p, 0, 1}, 
      Assumptions -> Element[{x1, x2, x3, x4, y1, y2, y3, 
         y4, k, p} , Reals]]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Armed with @Feyre's observation that the components are all polynomials we can do this:

```
CoefficientList[ CoefficientList[MP[[1, 1]], k]. (1/Range[4]) ,p ]. (1/Range[4])
```

Many orders of magnitude faster than `Integrate` (Beware this does not check that the input is actually polynomial )

Process the whole array like this:

```
polyint[f_, v_] := 
 Module[ {cl = CoefficientList[f, v]} , cl.(1/Range[Length@cl])]

Map[ (polyint[polyint[#, k], p] // Simplify) & , MP, {2}]
```

7 seconds for the whole matrix.. Note this produces a result in a somewhat different form so you need to use `Simplify` to verify the same result as `Integrate`

Answer (score 4):

Note that the variables `k` and `p` only occur in positive polynomial terms ($ak^n$).
This means that:

```
Integrate[MP, k, p]/.{k->1,p->1}==Integrate[MP, {k, 0, 1}, {p, 0, 1}]
```

Checking with one element, we can see the speed of the two different approaches:

```
RepeatedTiming[Integrate[MP[[1, 1]], {k, 0, 1}, {p, 0, 1}];]
RepeatedTiming[Integrate[MP[[1, 1]], k, p];]
```

> `{25.5, Null}`
>
> `{4.28, Null}`

That's a significant time difference.

So run:

```
Integrate[MP, k, p]/.{k->1,p->1}
```

The assumptions here are irrelevant.